wireless keyboard and mouse on logitech unifying receiver do not work in Ubuntu 24.04 but in EFI boot menu
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 and use a Logitech unifying receiver USB stick for my wireless keyboard and mouse combo:

K540
M310

When I boot my PC both keyboard and mouse work in EFI boot menu.
However, when I boot into Ubuntu 24.04 only the keyboard works.
I installed solaar and it shows both mouse and keyboard connected. When I switch off and back on the mouse this is reflected in solaar, however, it has no impact on mouse function.
Both in solaar as well as dmesg the HID++ protocol is listed as being used.
As a side note: it all worked flawlessly in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04, all of a sudden it didn't work after some update in Ubuntu 22.04; I tried to fix this with upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 but that didn't work apparently.
Does someone have a clue?
Of course I will try to catch as much debug information as possible if guided by you.
Thanks.
